# How can I get variable value from other page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Here is my ajax code:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    include_once 'dbconnect.php';

    if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
     header("Location: /manopuslapis/index.php");
    }
    $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
    $userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);



    mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET credits=credits-something WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);  
    ?>
```

How can I get marked value from other page?

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET credits=credits-**something** WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
```

Comment: There's no "ajax" here.  This is PHP code.  As for the value you want to get, where *is* that value?  Where would you be getting it from?  What is the "other page"?

Comment: i want to get it from var something = value; from other my website page called page.php

Comment: If your "other website" is indeed an entirely separate website (on another server) then you'd need to make an HTTP request to that site to get that value.  If it's "your" website then you can expose an API of some kind to return the value.  Otherwise, you can make a request to just get the page itself and parse the value from that.  It's really not clear what *specifically* you're trying to do.

Comment: Set another Session...

Comment: same website other page not other website

Comment: @Aurelijus1: You're going to have to be clear about what you're trying to accomplish here.  If you're trying to get a value from code, then include the code which has that value.  What specifically is *stopping you* from using whatever the value is?  "A value from a page" could mean just about anything.

Comment: I need to get that value from other page because that varriable value is changing, I use ajax.php to insert data into database and I can't define that value in ajax.php because that value have to by equal to specific value that are taken from input in other page

Comment: @Aurelijus1: Nothing you're saying makes sense.  You seem to be tossing around a lot of terminology without knowing what any of it means, which is making it very difficult to help you.  Can you provide a small yet complete example in the question?  It's really not clear what AJAX has to do with anything, since the only code we see is server-side.  How is the other page related to this page in the overall workflow?  Is the value client-side or server-side?  What calculates it?  When/how does it change?

Answer (score 0):

you can use SESSION or GET  to pass value to another page

using session

```
$_SESSION['value'] = $value ; // page 1 
$value = $_SESSION['value']; // page 2
```

using GET

```
<a href="page.php?value=<?php echo $value; ?>"></a> // page 1 
if(isset($_GET['value'])){
$value = $_GET['value'];
}
```